# How to connect Flex to Java using BlazeDS WAR file?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5, blazeds

I am new in Flex. I do not know how to connect Flash Builder to Java using BlazeDS. Anybody can help me with some screenshots. I search on net using this link:

http://cgrant.wordpress.com/2009/11/19/setting-up-flex-blazeds-in-flashbuilder/

Please help me with this. I do not know what I have to do at Java side or Flex side. Please help me and even i'm not able to understand what `web-inf` flex folder means here?

Answer (score 2):

In a Java EE application you can package your application in a WAR file. WAR files are zip files with a fixed structure. You case several folders in root and one specific that is WEB-INF. This last folder contains all private data that users outside application cannot access. Inside WEB-INF you have META-INF with metada data and classes folder. Classes folder store the compiled java classes. 
You may need to create inside WEB-INF folder a new folder called flex and put all xml config files inside it. 
Here if a good tutorial from adobe that may help you.
http://livedocs.adobe.com/blazeds/1/blazeds_devguide/help.html?content=lcoverview_4.html

Regards,
Breno